# ObjectMapper instance in unit test

Tags: java, spring, jackson, mockito

In my SpringBoot app my ObjectMapper object is autowired and contains registered modules as expected

[image]

My code:

[image]

and test:
[image]

Now in the Unit test section (with MockitoJUnitRunner) I'm unable to use the ObjectMapper instance, the registered module is null:
[image]

Even if I add mapper.findAndRegisterModules() the registered module is null and my date deserialization fails..

1. why not the same behavior in the code and in unit test?
2. how to register the same modules in my unit test?

Comment: Have you read a tutorial like? https://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-unit-testing-and-mocking-with-mockito-and-junit

Comment: When running with mockito you aren't using the Spring configured/created `ObjectMapper`. There is no Spring involved here and thus nothing will be autowired and confiugred by Spring.

Comment: The, please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. Without a bit of your code, how do you expect us to tell you what is wrong with your setup?

Comment: added the code, the breakpoint is each time in the MyDataLoader constructor

Comment: @M.Deinum well, yes I understood that Spring create the ObjectMapper but miss that also configures it. thanks

Comment: Spring (and Spring Boot extends a little on it) uses  `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderr` to construct the `ObjectMapper`.  In that class there is logic to detect some well known Jackson modules. When found those will automatically be actived. You can use this class as well to construct an instance.

Comment: great good to know, will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Utility class to register modules to `ObjectMapper` instance.

```
public static ObjectMapper newObjectMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return configureObjectMapper(objectMapper);
}
```

Then use this method in your actual code and in your test case to avoid different behaviours. This way you can have a consistant `ObjectMapper` in anywhere in your application whether it is test or actual code.

```
public static ObjectMapper configureObjectMapper(final ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return objectMapper
            .registerModule(new LocaleModule())
            .registerModule(new DateTimeDeserializationModule())
            .registerModule(new DateTimeSerializationModule())
            .registerModule(new JavaMoneyModule())
            .setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
}
```

Comment: Right, I assume Spring is doing that for us, and this need to be done manually in the test part.

Answer (score 1):

As a first bet you can call:

```
   mapper.registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
         .registerModule(new Jdk8Module())
         .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

The "find" part actually uses ServiceLoader mechanism and as the documentation states is considered potentially expensive